# Joining tables which don't share a field, but have a unique ID that is shared

Tags: sql, join

Beginner SQLmancer looking for a hand with something.

I have two tables I am trying to join but they don't share a column [tables A & B]. There is a table [C] which has a unique field that can be joined to both [Field 1 for Table A, 2 for Table B] and these two fields have a 1-to-1 relationship [For each value in Field 1, it has a corresponding unique value in Field 2 in Table C].

Is there a way for me to join table A & B "through" table C in a way that I can see data from just A&B?  Or, can I join them each to C to do this? If so, what kind of join is needed?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please update your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You basically join all 3.  This is very common way to associate records in databases, table C is often called a "Join table"

```
SELECT
    A.*, b.*
FROM
    A, B, C
WHERE
    A.foo = C.foo
    AND B.bar = C.bar
```

Comment: It's better to use the modern, explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the old, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: ideally you would explicitly name the joins

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip - will try this out and report back.